# what does max_allowed_packet take into considerations?

Tags: mysql, sql

If I add a `;` to my MySQL query does that count against the `max_allowed_packet` length? What about adding spaces? Does that count against it? Does MySQL automatically add a `;` if it's not present?

ie.

are the following the same in so far as `max_allowed_packet` length is concerned?:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (col_name) VALUES ( 1 ) , ( 2 );
INSERT INTO table_name (col_name) VALUES (1),(2)
```

If they are the same how can I programmatically know how long MySQL considers the query to be?

Comment: A short test you can do is to lower the limit to 1K for example and create a query greater than this. In the query after, add spaces or ;, in MySQL log you'll have the current packet size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the whitespace is of no concern for `max_allowed_packet`, which is a server variable.
As you can check the MySQL Client on the machine converts the String received to proper data type, while doing that it removes the extra unconcerned whitespace, and so does your MySQL Connector.

> *Which means both the Queries are treated as same*

So you should just be concerned about readability of the SQL query and forget the whitespaces.

**To Check**

- using WIRESHARK, capture the mysql packets.
- If interested in deep diving. Go through the Source Code for MySQL Client  or MySQL Connector that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The **max_allowed_packet** specifies the maximum length of a SQL statement to be executed after it has been received and pre processed by the server; that includes, for instance, the creation of the list of insert values (if any). So, by that time, there are no trailing spaces  and that sort of things. I'm not sure about the ";", but my best guess is that if it's not present, it's added when pre processing your statement.